# How to use if...else if function to divide numeric variable into groups in R and also the less than and equal operator show errors

Tags: r, if-statement

I have two basic problems with R code as the title.

Suppose I have a dataset like:

```
 w <- c( 0.005810275, -0.002758455, -0.005423105, -0.006692736, -0.010571356, 
        -0.006818535, -0.006943209, -0.004355057, -0.005951043, -0.002172708, 
        -0.003631478, -0.003957327, -0.005285497, -0.007682379, -0.007746185, 
        -0.011307843, -0.014013202, -0.013537595, -0.012859406, -0.013629170)
```

And I try to divide them into 4 groups, thus wrote the code as following:

```
 n=20
group <- rep(0,n)

for (i in 1:n){
    if (W[i] <= -0.05) { group[i]=1}
    else if ( -0.05 < W[i] <= -0.03  ) {group[i]=2}
    else if (-0.03 < W[i] <= -0.01) {group[i]=3}
    else group[i]=4
}
```

The error message is as following:

```
> group <- rep(0,n)
> for (i in 1:n){
+   if (W[i] <= -0.05) { group[i]=1}
+   else if ( -0.05 < W[i] <= -0.03  ) {group[i]=2}
Error: unexpected '<=' in:
"  if (W[i] <= -0.05) { group[i]=1}
      else if ( -0.05 < W[i] <="
>   else if (-0.03 < W[i] <= -0.01) {group[i]=3}
Error: unexpected 'else' in "  else"
>   else group[i]=4
Error: unexpected 'else' in "  else"
> }
Error: unexpected '}' in "}"
```

I really do not know why "<=" is an error.

Is there anyone could help? Thank you so much! BTW I use RStudio.

Comment: you could use the function 'cut' rather than the ifelse

Comment: `group = ifelse(w <= -0.05, 1, ifelse(-0.05 < w & w <= -0.03, 2, ifelse(-0.03 < w & w <= -0.01, 3, 4)))`

Answer (score 4):

Using the base `cut` function:

cut(w, breaks = c(-2,-0.05,-0.03,-0.01, 2), labels = c(1, 2, 3, 4), right = TRUE)

You could use right = TRUE or FALSE if the ' if the intervals should be closed on the right' or not.
Data:

```
w <- c( 0.005810275, -0.002758455, -0.005423105, -0.006692736, -0.010571356, 
        -0.006818535, -0.006943209, -0.004355057, -0.005951043, -0.002172708, 
        -0.003631478, -0.003957327, -0.005285497, -0.007682379, -0.007746185, 
        -0.011307843, -0.014013202, -0.013537595, -0.012859406, -0.013629170)
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `findInterval`

```
findInterval(w, c(-2, -0.05, -0.03, -0.01, 2))
#[1] 4 4 4 4 3 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 3 3 3 3 3
```

Answer (score 0):

`cut` is the way to go, as per ed_sans' answer. But your code doesn't work because R doesn't understand this:

```
-0.05 < W[i] <= -0.03
```

Here's an example of the right way to check a value against two conditions:

```
x = 5
x < 10
[1] TRUE
x > 1
[1] TRUE

1 < x < 10
Error: unexpected '<' in "1 < x <"

x > 1 & x < 10
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks. It seems like I have to two split conditions instead of one.

Answer (score 0):

This should work in your RStudio:

```
    W <- c( 0.005810275, -0.002758455, -0.005423105, -0.006692736, -0.010571356, 
    -0.006818535, -0.006943209, -0.004355057, -0.005951043, -0.002172708, 
    -0.003631478, -0.003957327, -0.005285497, -0.007682379, -0.007746185, 
    -0.011307843, -0.014013202, -0.013537595, -0.012859406, -0.013629170)

    n=20
    group <- rep(0,n)

    for (i in 1:n){
      if (W[i] < -0.05) { 
        group[i]=1} else {
          if (W[i]>= -0.05 & W[i]< -0.03) {
            group[i]=2} else {
                if (W[i]>= -0.03 & W[i]< -0.01) {
                  group[i]=3} else {group[i]=4}
            }
      }
    }
```

Note that R is not like SAS. You could not use two operators at the same assignment statement. For example, "1<= x <8" will not work in R. And you have to change it to a logic statement: "x >= 1 & x < 8" will work instead.